# Operations with user defined Datatype

Tags: haskell

I have a datatype

```
data Expr = ExprNum Double -- constants
          | ExprVar String -- variables
          | ExprAdd Expr Expr
          | ExprSub Expr Expr
          | ExprNeg Expr -- The unary '-' operator
          | ExprMul Expr Expr
          | ExprDiv Expr Expr
          deriving Show
```

If I have `(3* 4 + 5)` of datatype `Expr`
it should return `17` and if the expression includes a variable: `(3 * x)` it should return `ExprMul (ExprNum 3) (ExprVar "x")`

I tried doing it this way:

```
calculate (ExprMul a b) = a * b
calculate (ExprAdd a b) = a + b
calculate (ExprDiv a b) = a `div` b
calculate (ExprSub a b) = a - b
calculate (ExprVar a )= a
calculate (ExprNum a ) = Read a : Double
```

But I am unable to execute it.
What am I doing wrong here?

Another thing that I wish to know about is that if a user enters a value in Expr type ,and I need to convert it into string format,i.e,if User enters as

```
ExprAdd (ExprNum 1) (ExprVar "x")
```

I wish to get the output as follows

```
1+x
```

I tried using `Read` but I am unable to execute it.

Please if anyone can help.Thankyou.

Comment: You need to recursively call `calculate` on the components of the expression.

Comment: Can you please give me an exapmple..It would help.I am just unable to think in that way

Comment: (Among other problems.  See if you can get expressions involving only `ExprMul` first -- that will lead they way toward the others.

Comment: Okay, here's an example. `calculate (ExprMul a b) = (calculate a) * (calculate b)`.

Comment: for the terminating condition as i lead towards ExprVar ..    calculate (ExprNum a ) = Read a : Double
I gave this...i need to convert it into double.

Comment: Note you should have `Read a :: Double`, otherwise you're just using the cons operator wrong....

Comment: Why did you tag your question `wxhaskell` if you never ever mention wx? Also why did you tag it `real-world-haskell` when you don't mention the book? I left the `template-haskell` tag because, maybe, you wanted to do this parsing using TH, but, if this is not the case, that tag should also go. Don't just randomly select five tags just to fill all the available tag slots.

Comment: Well, what should the type of `calculate` be? `calculate (ExprVar a) = a` suggests `Expr -> String`, but almost all other expressions suggest `Expr -> Double`.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at your question and your examples, I think we can make this happen in a nice way using some type-classes to get some syntactic sugar.

You can find the complete code at the end but as Luke made a good point on me not explaining stuff let's start doing this.

First we have to take care on some minor problems in your implementation of `calculate` and then we can start looking for some syntactic sugar to enable input like `(3* 4 + 5) :: Expr`.

### implementing `calculate`

It was not 100% clear to me but I think you want your `calculate` to have this signature:

```
calculate :: Expr -> Expr
```

I most cases you see things like `evaluate :: Expr -> Maybe Double` but I think in this case (because you want `3 * x` to be `ExprMul (ExprNum 3) (ExprVar "x")`) we want indeed just to simplify terms using `calculate`.

So let's try to simplify things.

For expressions of the form `ExprNum` and `ExprVar` we can do nothing more to simplify things as it is, so let's be honest and say so:

```
calculate a@(ExprNum _) = a
calculate a@(ExprVar _) = a
```

If you did not see the `a@(ExprNum _)` syntax before it's just fancy way of matching `(ExprNum _)` but remembering the compllete matched expression in `a`.

With this in mind we have to take care of the more interesting cases - for example *multiplication*:

```
calculate (ExprMul a b) = a * b
```

The problem is your right side `a * b` Right now this cannot work as `(*)` needs to have it's operands to be in `Num` and `Expr` is not (yet).

Of course what we really want is to calculate the product if we can - meaning if both `a` and `b` are indeed numbers - or in this case `ExprNum`.

The easiest way to check this (I can come up with) is to recursivley simplify both operants `a` and `b` and then to use a `case` expression:

```
calculate (ExprMul a b) = let a' = calculate a
                              b' = calculate b
                          in case (a',b') of
                             (ExprNum a'', ExprNum b'') -> ExprNum (a''*b'')
                             _                          -> ExprMul a' b'
```

Let's look at this step by step:

- first it simplifies `a` and `b` into `a'` and `b'` using `calculate` recursivley
- then if both of these are numbers (`ExprNum`) it yield the product of their values as another `ExprNum`
- if they are not both `ExprNum`s it just yield an `ExprMul` using the simplified term

The last point is where a bit of the magic happens - because we yield the simplified terms the algorithm will try to simplify subterms even if a variable is around and we cannot get a complete evaluation.

#### refactoring a bit

Now we can do the same to the other expressions like `ExprDiv`, `ExprAdd`, ... but I did not really like to repeat the stuff again and again so let's refactor this out:

```
operateOnNums :: (Expr -> Expr -> Expr) 
              -> (Double -> Double -> Double) 
              -> Expr -> Expr -> Expr
operateOnNums def f a b = let a' = calculate a
                              b' = calculate b
                          in case (a',b') of
                            (ExprNum a'', ExprNum b'') -> ExprNum (f a'' b'')
                            _                          -> def a' b'

operateOnNum :: (Expr -> Expr) 
             ->  (Double -> Double) 
             -> Expr -> Expr
operateOnNum def f a = let a' = calculate a
                       in case a' of
                         ExprNum a'' -> ExprNum (f a'')
                         _           -> def a'
```

This is really just the same we did above even if these might seem to be a bit more complicated.
Again we only check if we can simplify subterms (two for `operateOnNums` and only one for `operateOnNum`) into `ExprNum` expressions and if so apply the
value of those to a function `f` (that will be the operations on the real numbers - like `(*)` for `ExprMul` or `negate` for `ExprNeg) and if not use`def`(meaning *defaults*) to wrap the simplified subterms into`Expr`s again.

Calculate itself now look rather nice (or so I think):

```
calculate :: Expr -> Expr
calculate (ExprMul a b) = operateOnNums ExprMul (*) a b
calculate (ExprAdd a b) = operateOnNums ExprAdd (+) a b
calculate (ExprDiv a b) = operateOnNums ExprDiv (/) a b
calculate (ExprSub a b) = operateOnNums ExprSub (-) a b
calculate (ExprNeg a)   = operateOnNum ExprNeg negate a
calculate a             = a
```

and I think we can move on.

### enabling syntactic sugar: implementing some type-classes

#### `Num`

This leaves us with the problem that we want to be able to input something like `3*4+5 :: Expr`.

Now there is a basic type-class named `Num` that provides us exactly with the means to do so.
You basically have to tell Haskell how to do a big enough subset of the basic math-operators like `*`, `+`, .. together with a function `fromIntegral` that will translate numbers like `0`, `1`, `2`, ... into `Expr`.

What's really nice here is, that we have those operators and even the `fromIntegral` already handy in form of our *type-constructors* `ExprMul`, `ExprAdd`, .. and `ExprNum`.

So let's make `Expr` an instance of `Num`:

```
instance Num Expr where
  a + b         = ExprAdd a b
  a * b         = ExprMul a b
  negate a      = ExprNeg a
  fromInteger n = ExprNum (fromInteger n)
  abs _         = undefined
  signum _      = undefined
```

Easy isn't it?

**Note** that I cheated with the `abs` and `signum` functions. If you like you can implement these too if you add other `Expr` cases for them and complement the `calculate` function accordingly - but for the examples the OP gave they are not really needed here.

With this done this will already work:

```
> calculate $ 3*4+5
ExprNum 17.0

> calculate $ 3*4 + ExprVar "a"
ExprAdd (ExprNum 12.0) (ExprVar "a")
```

#### `IsString`

@behklir suggested to implement this type-class as well - using this and the **OverloadedString** extension we will be able to evaluate something like this:

```
> calculate $ 3*4+"a"
ExprAdd (ExprNum 12.0) (ExprVar "a")
```

*OverloadedStrings* is there to translate `"a"` using the `fromString` from `IsString` instead of just compiling it into a `[char]`, so let's implement `IsString` - which again is really easy as we already have `fromString` in the form of `ExprVar`:

```
instance IsString Expr where
  fromString = ExprVar
```

Don't forget to enable `OverloadedStrings` with `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` in source.
In GHCi you might want to
 - start it with `ghci -XOverloadedStrings`
 - `:set -XOverloadedStrings` inside GHCi

#### `Fractional`

This one was a suggestion from  @ØrjanJohansen to enable us to write things like

I think you can get this working something like this:

```
> calculate $ "a" / 4.5
ExprDiv (ExprVar "a") (ExprNum 4.5)
```

It's much like `Num` for fractional values and the division - I think you know what comes by now:

```
instance Fractional Expr where
  fromRational r = ExprNum (fromRational r)
  a / b          = ExprDiv a b
```

That's it - please make sure to point me to things not 100% clear or misspelled.

## How to evaluate Variables

You might ask how you could evaluate Variables.

As we are no longer interested in a resulting expression but only in it's value let's call it `evaluate`:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

evaluate :: [(String, Double)] -> Expr -> Double
evaluate env (ExprMul a b) = evaluate env a * evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprAdd a b) = evaluate env a + evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprDiv a b) = evaluate env a / evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprSub a b) = evaluate env a - evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprNeg a)   = negate $ evaluate env a
evaluate _   (ExprNum n)   = n
evaluate env (ExprVar v)   = fromMaybe 0 $ lookup v env
```

Most of this should be straight forward - the only really new thing is `env`:
We need to know what value a variable has. So we pass in an environment with (*variable*,*value*) pairs. We can then use [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) together with [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) to find values for variables.

An example could look like this:

```
> evaluate [("a",5)] (3*4+"a")
17.0
```

As you can see I just provided a single pair, matching `"a"` to `5` - and then use an expression using `ExprVar "a"` (here of course *hidden* using `IsString` and `OverloadedStrings`).

In case the algorithm will not find a matching variable `lookup` will return `Nothing` and this is where `fromMaybe` comes into play: I decided to default variables to `0` in this case and this is exactly what `fromMaybe 0 :: Maybe Double -> Double` does (here).

#### if you don't want no default-to-0 behaviour

In case you don't like it that this will return `0` for variables not in the environment you can  change `evaluate` to be partial (or better: return `Maybe Double`) like this:

```
import Control.Applicative((<$>))
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

evaluate :: [(String, Double)] -> Expr -> Maybe Double
evaluate env (ExprMul a b) = liftM2 (*) (evaluate env a) (evaluate env b)
evaluate env (ExprAdd a b) = liftM2 (+) (evaluate env a) (evaluate env b)
evaluate env (ExprDiv a b) = liftM2 (/) (evaluate env a) (evaluate env b)
evaluate env (ExprSub a b) = liftM2 (-) (evaluate env a) (evaluate env b)
evaluate env (ExprNeg a)   = negate <$> evaluate env a
evaluate _   (ExprNum n)   = Just n
evaluate env (ExprVar v)   = lookup v env
```

This of course uses some heavy weaponary (`liftM2` brining `(*)` into the `Maybe` monad and `(<$>)` doing the same with `negate`).

Please understand that I cannot write another big block of text to explain those in detail.

Basically those are just there because I am to lazy to pattern-match on the results of `evaluate env a` and `evaluate env b` to do handle 4 cases (`Nothing, Nothing`, `Nothing, Just`, ...) - I am only interested in `Just,Just` anyway and those do exactly this: do the operation in the `Just` cases and return `Nothing` everywhere else.

### The complete code

For reference and easier copy&paste here is the complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Expressions where

import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.String (IsString(..))

data Expr = ExprNum Double -- constants
          | ExprVar String -- variables
          | ExprAdd Expr Expr
          | ExprSub Expr Expr
          | ExprNeg Expr -- The unary '-' operator
          | ExprMul Expr Expr
          | ExprDiv Expr Expr
          deriving Show

instance Num Expr where
  a + b          = ExprAdd a b
  a * b          = ExprMul a b
  negate a       = ExprNeg a
  fromInteger n  = ExprNum (fromInteger n)
  abs _          = undefined
  signum _       = undefined

instance Fractional Expr where
  fromRational r = ExprNum (fromRational r)
  a / b          = ExprDiv a b

instance IsString Expr where
  fromString     = ExprVar

evaluate :: [(String, Double)] -> Expr -> Double
evaluate env (ExprMul a b) = evaluate env a * evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprAdd a b) = evaluate env a + evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprDiv a b) = evaluate env a / evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprSub a b) = evaluate env a - evaluate env b
evaluate env (ExprNeg a)   = negate $ evaluate env a
evaluate _   (ExprNum n)   = n
evaluate env (ExprVar v)   = fromMaybe 0 $ lookup v env

calculate :: Expr -> Expr
calculate (ExprMul a b) = operateOnNums ExprMul (*) a b
calculate (ExprAdd a b) = operateOnNums ExprAdd (+) a b
calculate (ExprDiv a b) = operateOnNums ExprDiv (/) a b
calculate (ExprSub a b) = operateOnNums ExprSub (-) a b
calculate (ExprNeg a)   = operateOnNum ExprNeg negate a
calculate a             = a


operateOnNums :: (Expr -> Expr -> Expr) ->  (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Expr -> Expr -> Expr
operateOnNums def f a b = let a' = calculate a
                              b' = calculate b
                          in case (a',b') of
                            (ExprNum a'', ExprNum b'') -> ExprNum (f a'' b'')
                            _                          -> def a' b'

operateOnNum :: (Expr -> Expr) ->  (Double -> Double) -> Expr -> Expr
operateOnNum def f a = let a' = calculate a
                       in case a' of
                         ExprNum a'' -> ExprNum (f a'')
                         _           -> def a'
```

#### some examples

```
> calculate $ 3*4+5
ExprNum 17.0

> calculate $ 3*4+"a"
ExprAdd (ExprNum 12.0) (ExprVar "a")

> calculate $ 3*"a"+5
ExprAdd (ExprMul (ExprNum 3.0) (ExprVar "a")) (ExprNum 5.0)

> calculate $ 3*4+"a"
ExprAdd (ExprMul (ExprNum 3.0) (ExprNum 4.0)) (ExprVar "a")

> calculate $ "a" / 4.5
ExprDiv (ExprVar "a") (ExprNum 4.5)

> evaluate [("a",5)] (3*4+"a")
17.0
```

which is (I think) what you wanted to start with

#### remarks:

Don't forget to enable `OverloadedStrings` in GHCi if you want to try this:
 - start it with `ghci -XOverloadedStrings`
 - `:set -XOverloadedStrings` inside GHCi

Comment: An additional fun little hack, with `OverloadedStrings`, you could define `instance IsString Expr where fromString = ExprVar`, then you could have such fun expressions as `calculate $ 1 + 2 * 3 + "a"` and remove the need to have the extra `ExprVar` in the expression itself.

Comment: You probably also want an `instance Fractional Expr` - that gives you division and floating point numerals.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen why not :D

Comment: -1 for complete implementation without much explanation. (I prefer hints, but a write-up explaining the different components is acceptable. But this is essentially bare code without illuminating how or why it was made this way.)

Comment: @luqui I appreciate your feedback Luke (ouch) - I hope it's now *acceptable*

Comment: @CarstenKönig, very thorough write-up, this gives some good study fodder.  I like the way the `operateOnNums` helper is motivated by the pattern in `calculate`. I didn't mean to be harsh, I just value being direct. Thanks for improving your answer!  :-)

Comment: @luqui no problem really - the internets can be quite harsh sometimes but in this case it was constructive critique - yeah my first reaction was "WTF this is only SO" but *reason* won (this time) ;)